# Index table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I used MySQL and here's my table

```
|Col A(Primary)| Col B  | Col C      | Col D |
|1             | SOCCER | 2012-12-01 | P |
|2             | VOLLEY | 2012-12-14 | P |
|3             | SOCCER | 2012-12-01 | L |
|4             | VOLLEY | 2012-12-10 | P |
|3             | SOCCER | 2012-12-13 | L |
```

This table contain million rows. Frequently i used Col B and Col C as condition in my query.

I want to index that table. What column that must indexed? what type of index(primary, unique, fulltext)?

Comment: Nothing MUST be indexed on anything. This question is really basic (and asked a lot - do a search). There's lots of info about it around and only you can decide what would be useful for you and what is not.

Comment: @guunita . . . To answer this question, more informaiton is needed.  How many different values do columns B and C take?  What are examples of the filtering conditions?  Are the two columns always used together or typically used separately?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really

Comment: Thx for response all. @Gordon Linoff Col B just have 5 varian data and Col C have lot of varian. yes its always used together. Anyway, is index works on agregate function?

Comment: You can read about indexes and group by'sin MySQL here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-optimization.html.

Answer (score 1):

Column A is already PRIMARY KEY, so no more indexing it needed. You certainly can index the DATE column with normal KEY or INDEX.

As to Col. B, I'd suggest you use normalized form and store the text values in a different table and reference those using the INT id from that table in this table. It'll definitely save both the storage space and time taken to search the database. A good example of normalized table can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF).

As for last column, since you don't filter results for that, I don't think you need an index there.

After 1NF form has been applied an easy INDEX method will work.

Comment: Would an enum type offer the same efficiency improvements? Since technically MySQL stores the value as a number.

Comment: @NathanAdams For column D, yeah. As for Col B, I'd need a little more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a hard time with indexing this query.  `ColB` has only five values, which is a very high selectivity.  Unfortunately, indexes are not very useful on such a column.

You should put in a compound index on `(ColB, ColC)`.  This will work for queries where `ColB` is used with an `=` or `in` clause and you have any condition on `ColC` (except perhaps for `<>`).  However, if a typical query is going to be processing many rows in the table, say 5% or something like that, then an index may not help at all.

Comment: [Cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for building such an index.